# webサイトのデプロイ後にドメイン名でアクセス出来なくなった

Tags: ruby, aws

### 前提

Ruby(ruby on rails) で作った EC サイトを AWS の EC2 使ってデプロイした自分のサイト（ドメインも購入）が表示されなくなってしまったので質問させていただきます！

---

### 発生している問題

上記のようにデプロイした EC サイトなのですが、完成し、デプロイしてからしばらくはちゃんとアクセスしたら表示されていたのですが、それからしばらく放置していたら表示されなくなっていました。

現在アクセスすると

> このサイトにアクセスできません
>   www.(サイト名).work のサーバーの IP アドレスが見つかりませんでした。
>   (サイト名) work を Google で検索してください
>   ERR_NAME_NOT_RESOLVED

と表示されてしまいまして、 EC2 インスタンスの Elastic IP をブラウザ入力してアクセスすると、 nginx の青と白の画面、 Welcome to nginx on the Amazon Linux AMI! と表記されている画面になっていました。

放置していた間はだいたい１ヶ月くらいで、その間に変わったことといえば、 PC（mac）アップデート等で再起動したのと、再起動してからターミナルは使っていない点くらいです。

デプロイ時参考にした記事はこちらです↓
[初心者向け：AWS(EC2)にRailsのWebアプリをデプロイする方法 - Qiita](https://qiita.com/iwaseasahi/items/d5f2ef3eac5e349a8f7d)

以上ですが、再度このサイトを表示するにはどうしたらよいでしょうか？

対策など何か思いつく方いましたら宜しくお願い致しますm(._.)m

---

### 補足情報

ターミナルで ssh 接続して EC2 に入り、そこで、こちら入力しました結果が以下です。

```sh
[test_user@ip-10-0-1-174 ~]$ nslookup www.（サイト名）.work

Server:     10.0.0.2
Address:    10.0.0.2#53

** server can't find www.（サイト名）.work: NXDOMAIN
```

Comment: `ERR_NAME_NOT_RESOLVED`の原因は、ドメイン名`www.(サイト名).work`をIPアドレスに変換できないというエラーです。まずは、ターミナルで`nslookup www.(サイト名).work`を実行し名前解決できるのか調べるべきです。その結果を補足情報として質問に追記すると、回答が得られやすいはずです。

Comment: 結果補足致しました。引き続き宜しくお願いしますm(._.)m

Comment: DNS名前解決の問題っぽいですね。切り分けが必要だと思いますが、購入したドメインのDNSはどうなさってますか？ Route53、レンタルサーバ、自前サーバーで運用、など有ると思いますがいかがでしょうか。

Comment: マルチポスト　https://teratail.com/questions/140065

Comment: DNSはRoute53で設定しました！

Comment: 自己解決できました！
問題はドメインがCLIENT　HOLDされていたことでした。
登録メアドの有効性を確認とらせれば解除されるとのことで、過去のメールからその旨の内容を探したところ見つかったのでそこのURLからアクセスしただけで解除されました。
皆さまお時間いただきありがとうございましたm(._.)m

Comment: 自己解決した場合は、自分自身で回答を書き、その回答を承認して下さい。詳しくは[「自分の質問に回答できますか?」](http://ja.stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer)をご覧下さい。

Answer (score 1):

自己解決できました！

問題の原因はドメインがCLIENT HOLDされていた様でした。登録メアドの有効性を確認すれば解除されるとのことで、過去のメールからその旨の内容を探したところ見つかったので、そのURLにアクセスすることで解除されました。

---

この回答は [@take さんのコメント](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/questions/47347/web%e3%82%b5%e3%82%a4%e3%83%88%e3%83%87%e3%83%97%e3%83%ad%e3%82%a4%e5%be%8c%e3%81%ae%e7%92%b0%e5%a2%83%e3%81%ae%e8%b3%aa%e5%95%8f#comment48917_47347) を元にコミュニティwikiとして投稿しています。